# How would you go about proving this?

Tags: combinatorics

Consider the following tile puzzle. You have a 2 × 3 square grid, and on the grid you have five square tiles numbered 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 filling all but the bottom-right square (referred to the current empty square). The starting position is the following arrangement
A move in this game consists of sliding a tile into the empty square from a square adjacent to the empty square (leaving its previous location empty). No tile can leave the grid whether by lifting it up or sliding it off the sides. Is it possible to obtain the following configuration from the starting position in a series of moves? Explain.

Comment: You're missing some details here like the "starting position" and the "following configuration."  Also, since you clearly are copy and pasting this question from somewhere, is it homework?  If so, what are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: What is the 'following configuration'?

Comment: the starting configuration is a 2x3 grid with from left to right, 1, 2, 3 on the top row and 4, 5, empty space on the bottom row

Comment: the final configuration is the same but 2 and 1 are swapped

Comment: i already no the answer is no because i mapped out essentially all possible cases but i need direction in going about writing the proof cohesively

Comment: Honestly, it looks like you'd get the most out of writing out your own attempt at a proof and getting commentary. Why not put that up as an answer?

Comment: Also, you should [edit] the question to supply the information about the starting position and the final configuration rather than leaving it in the comments where it might be missed.